# maven to package app jar, create project classpath, goals

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, maven

**Update** : solved by using assembly plugin to copy in artifacts, to a folder or create a redistributable zip file.
Do not know maven. Used STS/ eclipse to make a maven project that is a swing standalone application. App runs fine inside STS. [Example helped.](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/maven-assembly-example/releases)
{figured out how it's  getting the runner script. template is there in the source. maven just filters it and puts the current jar name. Now just need to figure out how to stop maving putting my app jar in the assembly lib (want it one level up so can click it and start, and 80 other jars are in lib), using ant for that now }

*Original question*
Cannot find the lib folder. Apparently the app refers to local jars in the maven local repo.

Can I tell maven to copy them to some folder under my project like dist/lib and make a full app jar in my dist/ (I do not care if dist is some other directory name -> if there is a maven default do not mind that). I want a distributable set of jars to ship.

When I build my project now it puts classes in the

> ./target/classes

directory ./ is my project folder here

My pom:-

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.selenium</groupId>

<artifactId>SA</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SA</name>
<url>http://sel2in.com</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.1_3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cssparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>cssparser</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-core-js</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
        <version>1.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20080701</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
        <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.w3c.css</groupId>
        <artifactId>sac</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>

                <!-- put your configurations here -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Did as Andreas suggested Added shade to pom :-

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- put your configurations here -->
                <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
                <resource>.txt</resource>
                <resource>resources/</resource>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

From IDE build :

Dont see anything

From command line if I give

```
mvn package  shade:shade
```

Then :-

```
[INFO] Including org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:2.33.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:2.33.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.webbitserver:webbit:jar:0.4.14 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0 in the shaded jar.
[DEBUG] Processing JAR /Users/manoj/Downloads/SA/target/SA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.873s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jul 06 22:08:17 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default-cli) on project SA: Error creating shaded jar: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default-cli) on project SA: Error creating shaded jar: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error creating shaded jar: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:528)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:221)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:176)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:288)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:199)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:323)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:388)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.shade(DefaultShader.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:458)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Used assembly (suggested by John Ament) as described here [maven-assembly-example/releases](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/maven-assembly-example/releases) or [zip](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/maven-assembly-example/archive/1.0.0.zip)

Got a big tar and zip with all the jars. Most of the work done. Now just need to unpack, make a script so I have

```
 project-home
   -> dist
   -->   MyApp.jar
   --> lib
   --->  other1.jar
   --->  other2.jar
   --> conf
   --->  myResources1.jpg
   --->  otherFiles2.xyz
```

Comment: looks like shade is one way to go. is there another to just dump all the libs in a separate directory, make a app.jar and a sh or text file with a classpath to include all? looks like current error is that there is a file called LICENSE in the /META-INF and maven wants to make a directory called by the same name too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While shade is a good solution, you may not want those dependencies in your JAR.  You can also use the assembly plugin to copy in artifacts, to a folder or create a redistributable zip file.

Comment: BTW, here's a quick intro to assembly.  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html Note that your assembly contents remain outside.

Comment: sigh that seems like it will work. now to figure it out! i guess i need to make something with the final app jar and tell it to include all the dependencies' binaries in the lib folder? And then look at making a classpath and launch script out of that

Comment: that worked ! What worked: it made a "SA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-default.tar.gz" which has a lib with all the dependent jars. yeah :-)  now any help to make a script to include all lib. use ant? anything in maven ?

Comment: Can't you declare your dependencies as a manifest entry to do that? http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

Comment: this should be part of the assembly?

Comment: No, the classpath setup is part of your JAR manifest, so you configure it in your JAR plugin.

Comment: Got that part to work. and actually read the github sample ... figured out how he is getting the runner script. template is there in the source. maven just filters it and puts the current jar name. Now just need to figure out how to stop maving putting my app jar in the aseembly lib (want it one level up so can click it and start, and 80 other jars are in lib)

Answer (score 2):

Create a [shaded jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) (UberJar) by adding this to your plugins section:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- put your configurations here -->
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Maven will create on jar that contains *all* classes from your sources and all of your dependencies.

Comment: +1 thank you for quick answer. but nothing new was created when I choose clean and build from STS Project. Went to the command line but that gave other errors. Do I need to do something before to tell it to package?

Comment: see question for new issues

Comment: That invalid signatur thingy may come from one of the jars. Have a look at the plugin web page and into the configuration. We can exclude files from jars, so you may try to exclude the offending manifest. `mvn package` should be sufficiant, `shade` is bound to that lifecycle phase (see "execution")

Comment: Going with assembly as i do not know how to find that bad jar, and assembly meets my basic requirement -> make maven copy all jars to one place.